# Best solution to block countries?

Tags: nginx, ip

I have a web application on which I want to block countries like China, Romania, etc.  I also want to block a large number of VPNs like hotspot shield, hidemyass, cyberghost, and so on.  I have a large list of around ~5500 CIDR format IP addresses which totals around 340 million Ip addresses.  I realize this is a huge number and is probably not efficient.  My site gets around 20 million page views per month.

Anyway, what I'm doing now:
I have nginx and am simply including a large text file which is around ~80kb into the server directive.  It's actually working and haven't really noticed a performance hit.  I still want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

What I don't want: Accept visits by only certain countries.  Hundreds of countries visit my website so this is not viable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from your question what Nginx configuration directives you are using. Anyway, AFAIK the most effective way of doing such things in Nginx is [`geo` module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) -- you'll have to `include` a large text file with IP blocks/ranges into `geo`, but internally Nginx does very fast lookups through this table.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists have been already optimized(sorted and ranged merged where applicable) and you are using the most efficient methods of nginx(such as the geo module in the other answer), then the only thing you could do to speed things up even more is create firewall entries(iptable ect...) which will compute whether a connection should be made at an even lower level , usually kernel and stopping things before they use the resources up the chain.  To say it another way, nginx will never even have to process the connection and use its resources to check if it is comes from the proper country.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use Peer block-100's of lists to help. Constantly updated. Also, if a site is blocked, however you need temp access to, allows for that as well.